# Deploy project Java EE on server (with EJBs and servlets)

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, hosting, server

I am currently working on a web project application using Java EE.
I have no knowledges on hosting and server
A friend who worked a lot with Java said me it will be difficult to host my project on a server... Especially because I use EJBs, Servlets / JSP, etc.

- Could you say me where can I host my project ? (OVH ? Google App Engine ? other ?)
- Have you got a price for it ?
- Have you got a tutorial for it ?

Many thanks for your answers.

Comment: so simple to deploy a project on jboss/tomcat/etc. takes no more than 1 click. About a hosting.... it depends what you want, and it is an individual option. maybe here is the wrong place to ask. or you should ask "what specification I need on a host, to deploy my project, with this technologies".

Comment: you can deploy your project on any JEE supporting app server like glassfish, weblogic, etc, I think your fried meant in case of your project architecture and the way of using EJB, but if you don't know where can you deploy, how you are developing and testing your project!!??

Comment: Sorry, the word "deploy" was not the right one I think. I deploy my project on a GlassFish server, but only in local. I will edit my post. Thank for you answers

Answer (score 0):

Yo will need an EJB cotainer to deploy your application, as you use EJBs: Glassfish, JBoss AS ...

About hosting, it really depends on your requirements. But probably you are fine with a free service in the beginning.

You can try [this](https://www.openshift.com/web-hosting/java) but there are other options for free hosting of java web applications.

Comment: Thank Cristian for your answer. I will try the free offer of you website and come back to validate your answer if it works :)